# Quando é que se começou a chamar "celebridade" a pessoas célebres?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Eu imaginava que isto era coisa dos últimos vinte ou trinta anos, mas se calhar andei desatento. Porque ando a ler *Os Gatos* de Fialho de Almeida, e num artigo originalmente publicado a 20 de Setembro de 1891 encontro o seguinte (4ª edição, 1920, 4º volume, p. 226; grafia original, negrito meu):

> Seguiu-se um interregno bastante obscuro d’alguns mezes, períodos de vaccas magras, constante de contas por pagar e de iluminação com velas de cebo, durante o qual o *Trunfo-Club* hibernou n’uma casinhola somenos no Bairro-Alto (a costa d’Africa para onde o arrésto varre, nas epochas de crise, todas as nossas **celebridades** galantes que liquidam)

Então isto foi um uso excecional do Fialho de Almeida, que era muito inventivo na linguagem, ou o termo já estava em uso com este sentido naquela época? Quais são os primeiros exemplos de uso registados em Portugal e no Brasil?

Já agora, talvez ajude, *célébrité* no francês e *celebrity* no inglês também têm este sentido de ‘pessoa famosa’ e poderão ter influenciado o português. No francês este sentido está atestado em 1831 [(CNRLT)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/c%C3%A9l%C3%A9brit%C3%A9); no inglês, em 1849 [(Etymoline)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=celebrity).

Answer (score 1):

Optei por pesquisar os livros [no google books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=celebridade&espv=2&biw=1536&bih=744&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F2%2F500%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F2%2F1700&tbm=bks#q=celebridade&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/2/500,cd_max:1/2/1700,sbd:1&tbm=bks&start=20).

Creio que o livro mais antigo na lista, [Vida de dom frei Bertolameu dos Martyres da Ordem dos Pregadores arcebispo e Senhor de braga Primas das Espanhas](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ejJfgR_PmtQC&pg=RA6-PT101&dq=celebridade&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2raz82czRAhVlLMAKHavxC9w4FBDoAQhGMAk#v=onepage&q=celebridade&f=false), datado de 1619 autoria de Frei Luis Cácegas, faz o uso da palavra celebridade no mesmo contexto da pergunta, na seguinte passagem:

> Porque sua celebridade illustre em fama e reputação não se vence em
>   pouco tépo: e quando lha não a concedamos de mais annos que duzentos
>   antes dos Martyres já fica com ventagé de mil e quinhentos de
>   anfianidade na primeira fúdação e no nome.

É claro que nesta passagem o uso de celebridade está apenas indicar uma pessoa de renome, provavelmente alguém da burguesia ou realeza. Essa pessoa parece tratar-se de Viana.

Eu não encontrei nenhuma informação sobre o autor, apenas que [Frei Luís de Sousa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frei_Lu%C3%ADs_de_Sousa) parece ter complementado uma obra dele, "História de Sao Domingos"

> ...Foi cronista da sua Ordem em Portugal, tendo viajado por diversos
>   conventos, recolhendo materiais para completar a monumental obra
>   "História de São Domingos", cujo esboço tinha sido iniciado por Frei
>   Luís de Cácegas anos antes.

Aliás o autor Frei Luís de Sousa reformulou esta mesma obra também, segundo a informação na capa, não me parece tratar-se da mesma obra.

---

Contudo eu atrevia-me a responder, desde que a palavra existe. Todos os dicionários que vi<sup>[1](http://www.aulete.com.br/celebridade), [2](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/celebridade), [3](https://www.dicio.com.br/celebridade/), [4](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/celebridade). [5](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/celebridade/)</sup> apontam que celebridade é um substantivo (ou seja, neste caso, uma forma de chamar algúem) .

Ja célebre é a qualidade de ser uma celebridade, ou seja célebre é um adjetivo, enquanto celebridade é substantivo.

Apenas acontece que este substantivo traz também qualidades a ele associadas tal como fama e notoriedade.

---

Parece que autor da pergunta está a falar da qualidade de ser uma celebridade em vez de ter celebridade. É uma diferença muito ténue, mas de fato existente.

Após ter lido descrições de umas quantas dezenas de livros [limitei a minha pesquisa para "é uma celebridade"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%C3%A9+uma+celebridade%22&espv=2&biw=1536&bih=744&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F500%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1890&tbm=bks). Pelo menos no livro [A Marqueza: romance](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eYo9AQAAMAAJ&q=%22%C3%A9+uma+celebridade%22&dq=%22%C3%A9+uma+celebridade%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj__IbD_87RAhWFDcAKHRvFABAQ6AEIGjAA), datado de 1883, tem a ocorrência com este ligeiro detalhe presente, sem quaisquer dúvidas.

> Ella é uma pequenita árabe, que vem lá dos confins do deserto; elle é uma celebridade. É Maximiliano Danglars, o viajante.

O outro livro presente na lista também parece encaixar, mas não parece falar de ninguém em especifico. Trata-se de [Bom-senso e bom-gosto: Carta ao [excellentissimo] senhor Antonio Deliciano de Castilho](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a64RAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA44&dq=%22%C3%A9+uma+celebridade%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj__IbD_87RAhWFDcAKHRvFABAQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A9%20uma%20celebridade%22&f=false), datado de 1865 autoria de Anthero do Quental.

> Quem quer escrever bem só porque seja uma celebridade da sua terra, e não é 
>   uma celebridade só porque escreve bem, esse tal pode tomar de assalto a opinião:....

Comment: Eu nao fiz nenhuma referencia a Portugal ou Brasil porque a obra que encontrei é dum autor cuja nacionalidade é desconhecida, embora seja porovável que seja português, uma vez que Frei Luís de Sousa também era português.

Comment: Agora tá a cama a chamar-me. Amanhã vou ter que ler aquilo com mais atenção, mas a minha primeira impressão é que *celebridade* ali significa 'qualidade de célebre*, não uma pessoa.

Comment: Bruno, todos os dicionários que indicas dão *celebridade* mais ou menos como sinónimo de 'fama'. Também é substantivo, mas uma coisa é *celebridade* = *fama* (Ele atingiu grande celebridade); outra é *celebridade* = *pessoa célebre*. É este segundo sentido que eu quero saber quando começa. Estive a ler outra vez, e acho que no teu texto é o primeiro sentido, que celebridade não se adquire em pouco tempo. Deixo uma citação ligeiramente expandida (a seguir):

Comment: "Esse Viana já então possuía autoridade e o nome que hoje tem: bem se segue que uma coisa e outra [ele] tinha de muitos anos atrás. Porque uma celebridade ilustre em fama e reputação não se vence [ganha, adquire?] em pouco tempo"

Comment: @Jacinto Eu nao percebo, porque célebre é aquele que tem fama também [olha aqui no priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%A9lebre). Aliás eu complementei a minha respsota exatamente com o substantivo/adjetivo por esse mesmo motivo.

Comment: Sim, eu sei, mas vê lá se no texto que tu citas, na minha citação alargada, *celebridade* não parece significar antes 'qualidade de célebre' em vez de 'pessoa célebre'. Juntei mais informação na pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto, Pois é, estou contigo. Celebridade no seu texto nada tem a ver com pessoas.

Comment: @Jacinto Tratam-se de pessoas certamente, uma vez que apenas pessoas podem escrever.

Comment: Os dois novos exemplos, sim, é claramente "celebridade" = "pessoa célebre". No primeiro, continuo na minha. Eu interpreto a frase como "não se ganha/obtém celebridade (= fama) em pouco tempo. Se fosse "celebridade" = "pessoa célebre", como interpretarias a frase? "Não se vence (em conflito?) uma pessoa célebre"? Não parece fazer sentido no contexto.